# How to deal with special character in MVVM data binding values

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

Hi guys I have been searching for this for a day now  . I have an issue with one of my data binding where by i have Entry that is data bound to ViewModel property but now ,if a user type a value with a special character like "BB\20" the value that is passed to the binding property is "BB\20" . Am using Xamarin forms and Xaml as my underlying UI code. How can i deal with this issue?

Comment: Sorry what is your question?

Comment: I want to know how can i deal with Xml parser escape characters in Mvvm data binding for example when a user enters BB\20 on an Entry bound to MakeModel which is a View model property  the backslash is escaped with another one to give a value of BB\\20  which is passed to this property by Mvvm binding, so am ending up getting a wrong value. I not sure if am clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that .NET adds the additional backslash as an escape character to the string, however the value remains the same. It's only visible when you're live debugging your code and you inspect the property. As long as you handle the value is will still read `BB\20`. Just check it's length and you'll notice it's 5 and not 6. Or display it in a `Label` or write it to a file.